# Facebook PHP-SDK 4 Check Post Has Been Posted

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, get

I'm trying to figure out the code to check if a post has been posted to a users wall.

Using `->getProperty('id')` I got the post id 1389990597967796_1391264054507117, but how do I check if it is on a user's wall? I've tried this:

```
$request1 = new FacebookRequest(
        $session,
        'GET',
        '/page_id/feed'
    );

// get response
$graphObject1 = $response1->getGraphObject()->asArray();
// print profile data
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject1, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

Can anyone help? I Could do with a good example to get my head around, as the facebook docs don't really explain it very well.

Comment: side question: may i ask why you want to know if something got posted?

Comment: I would also like to know if it has been shared how many time etc. Becuase you get free download as long as the post has been shared

Comment: that´s not allowed, see my answer

Comment: You should read https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the user feed, you need the `read_stream` or `user_status` permission.

The first one will most likely not get approved, see the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

The second one only lists the own posts, but you have to use `/me/statuses`.

Keep in mind that `user_status` needs to get reviewed too, and you will not get it approved just for checking if someone posted on his wall. You are not allowed to force users to post something:

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Meaning: Users need to share/post something because they really want to, not because they get something if they do it. You want to give them something for sharing ("you get free download as long as the post has been shared"). That´s not allowed according to the platform policy, and you will never get any permission for this approved by Facebook.

Comment: I have used free downloads before which ask for a post then after i have connected to the facebook app and it has been posted i get the free download so how do they do that if it is not allowed they join my app first.

Comment: I ask the users permintion first then if they deciced to share just want to check I am not trying force users just ask permison.

Comment: they are probably using an old v1.0 app, but it´s still not allowed and it will stop working even for them after april 2015. btw, it IS allowed to incentivice "joining your app" - see "Only incentivize a person to log into your app".

Comment: you want to give them something for sharing. that´s not allowed according to the platform policy, and you will never get any permission for this approved by facebook. i will add that to my answer to make it perfectly clear.